# How to split a string twice and add it to a linked list?

Tags: java, regex, string

I tried  to split a string and added it to a linked list. Each node in the linked list is a polynomial boundary. I tried this but it gave me a dangling meta character exception, what did I do wrong?

```
 String s = "X^2+3x+5";
 LinkedList p_list = new LinkedList();

 s.toLowerCase();
 s.replace("*x", "x");
 s.replace("x^", "x");
 s.replaceAll("--","+");
 s.replaceAll("+-", "-");
 s.replaceAll(" ", "");
 String []  st = s.split("(?=[+-])");
 String [] st2 = new String[2];

 for(int i=0;i<=st.length;i++){
    if(st[i].contains("x")){
        st2=st[i].split("x");
        if(st2[0].length()== 0 && st2[1].length()== 0){
            p_list.addFirst(1,1);
        }else if(st2[0].length()== 1 && st2[1].length()== 0){
                p_list.addFirst(Integer.parseInt(st2[0]),0);
        }
    } else {
        p_list.addFirst(Integer.parseInt(st2[0]),Integer.parseInt(st2[1]));
    }


 }  


 p_list.printList();
```

Comment: post the StackTrace !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) accepts a String, but [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) accepts a **regex**, and a regex that begins with `+` is invalid. You have two options:

- escape the character `+`, in Java it's `\\+`
- use [`Pattern#quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)

Important note: String is *immutable*, you should assign the result to a new String.

Answer (score 4):

The stack trace is pretty self-explanatory:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta 
character '+' near index 0
+-
^
```

You need to escape the `+` symbol in the following line:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\+-", "-"); // Note: you need to assign the result back to 's'
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all String is immutable, so:

```
String s = "X^2+3x+5";

s.toLowerCase();
s.replaceAll(....)
s.substring(etc ...)
```

Will give you same String as declared at the beginning. The replaceAll() method takes a regex as the first parameter. And the "*" has special meaning in a regex. You will need to escape it with \.

```
String result = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\*x", "x")
                .replace("x^", "x").replaceAll("--", "+")
                .replaceAll("\\+-", "-").replaceAll("\\+-", "-")
                .replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer (you already got 2 of them) but very important to note that `String` is immutable so the manipulation methods (e.g. `toLowerCase`, `replace` etc..) will produce a new string and will not modify the `String` object on which they are called so assign the result to your string in order for the changes to be in effect, i.e:

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
```